# How to access an array elements child, while looping?

Tags: javascript, gsap

I have divided my home page into 4 divs with the class of ".div-pics". And my goal is everytime you hover on one of them a description appears /with the class of ".div-desc". The animation happens through Greensock TimelineLite and the initial position of the description divs is "top: 100%".

The code I currently have works, but not with the desired effect. Right now once you hover any of the divs (.div-pics), all description divs (.div-desc) will appear. 
Instead I would like only the hovered div's description to come on screen, but I don't know how to target it.

```js
function loopDivs() {
  divArray.forEach(div => {
    div.addEventListener("mouseover", showDetails);

    function showDetails() {
      tlDetails = new TimelineLite();

      tlDetails
        .to(".div-desc", 0.5, {
          top: "0%"
        });
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="home-about" class="div-pics div-left">
  <h1 class="div-title">About</h1>
  <div class="div-desc dl">
    <div class="div-arrow">
      <div class="arrow-part arrow-top"></div>
      <div class="arrow-part arrow-bottom"></div>
    </div>
    <p class="div-text dt-left">
      Lorem ipsum ...
    </p>
    <li class="div-link"><a href="#">Order parts</a></li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated (:

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `tlsDetails.to(".div-desc", 0.5, {top: "0%"});` might being using `querySelectorAll` when you pass `".div-desc"`

I would suggest passing the mouseevent from the dom.

```
function showDetails(event) {
  tlsDetails = new TimelineLite();

  tlsDetails.to(event.target, 0.5, {
    top: "0%"
  });
}
```

looking at the GreenSock docs I found that you can pas the target element as the first parameter. This should give you a proper target vs ALL of the `.div-desc` classes that it could find.

Comment: Hm this does target the element it is on. But in my case I can't hover the .div-desc, because it is sent all the way down and it's invisible. My initial thought was to hover its parent and then it would appear. 
But with the approach you suggested maybe it would work if I position the .div-desc on top of the parent and play with its opacity.

Comment: I would love to answer any follow up questions but the above solved your immediate problem yes?

Answer (score 0):

```
function loopDivs() {
    var i = 0;
    divArray.forEach(div => {
        div.addEventListener("mouseover", showDetails(i));

        i ++;
        function showDetails() {
            tlDetails = new TimelineLite();

            var divDesc = document.getElementByClassName(".div-desc");

            tlDetails
                .to(divDesc[i], 0.5, {
                    top: "0%"
                });
        }
    });
}
```

This is untested so i'm not 100% sure this will work however the idea for a possible solution is present, first ensure you can access the index of each of the divs then get the divs using some form of document call then simply pass the index of the element you want to animate to the tween.